# PHP (cURL, headers, COOKIES) and more

Tags: php, cookies, curl, request-headers

I will try to explain what I am trying to reach the best way I can.

Let's say there is a page that shows information and it has cookies ( I can see the cookies through Firecookie [Firefox add-on in Firebug]) I am able to print the cookies in my localhost through

```
$cookies = array();
foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
        parse_str($matches[1], $tmp);
        $cookies += $tmp;
    }
}

print_r($cookies);
```

but the original page has request headers, and what I am trying to do is get the request header and make a request to that same page. I guess I have two questions, do I get the request header through COOKIES or separately. And how do I get the request headers of a page and send a request to that page with those request headers? I tried lots of things and couldn't succeed. I don't have the codes I've tried since I constantly try new things therefore can't paste what I have, only the file I pasted.

Comment: because I it might be used to do this

Comment: Do you want to send request to another webpage with proper COOKIE and Headers?

Comment: yes sir, I want to set request to another webpage with the cookies and headers I got from that same page

Comment: and I don't know how to get that page's request-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP with apache you can get request headers using function `apache_request_headers`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Comment: It gives the headers of my page, but I want the headers of the page that I am accessing through file_get_contents()

Comment: well is that page in your control? are you calling contents from 3rd party website or from one which is under your own control?

Comment: how does it differ in those 2 cases?

Comment: If the 2nd page is in your control you can print apache_http_headers from that page along with content using some separator.

Comment: unfortunately it is not, but isn't it possible to get the request headers after I do file_get_contents() of that age? Because I can get the cookies of that page, I was thinking there should be a method for request-headers

Comment: no I am aware of no way using which you can do that. Because we are looking for some information which is not in our control - that headers are available to that page and w/o being returned from that page you can't have. Cookies are stored at Client browser so that is possible for you to get them somehow.